# Huge Processing Time for Gtag making the site unresponsive

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, iis-8, google-analytics-4

Loading the Google tag through Google Tag Manager on our site and it is sending data to two destinations, GA4 and Google Ads.

The issue is that the gtag is taking forever to load (13 seconds). In Pagespeed insights it shows anywhere between 10-30 seconds!

I've implemented GTM and Gtag many times and have never had this happen.

The delay is reported as Processing Time in the main thread, after which it triggers a doubleclick iframe. If I disable the Google Signals collection it still takes forever to load.

[image]

We removed the Gtag from firing which instantly resolved the issue.

Comment: What is your code snippet?  Is it async?

Comment: Standard code from the install interface. Have noticed that all pages on the site have this issue except the cart page (which doesn't process or load our categories for ecommerce products)  https://www.kegoutlet.com/cleaning-equipment-sanitizing.html and https://www.kegoutlet.com/cart/cart.aspx

Comment: Make sure to implement your GTM code in the latest section, under the necessary assets of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Update: [Here](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/simoahava_edit-ive-updated-this-text-to-emphasize-activity-7140671108315332608-g2wI/) Simo goes through the new feature gtag enabled by default. That feature aims to detect user-provided data automatically. It does so by parsing the whole page looking through it all with a regex. This process effectively blocks the main thread depending on what content the regex stumbles upon, as it is usually the case with regular expressions. Disabling the feature should fix the problem.

Old answer:

As Stephen indicated, the snippet has to be async to avoid blocking the main thread regardless of whether it's "standard" or not.

Plus, you don't implement GTM and Gtag. You implement either or. GTM loads gtag whenever it's needed. Many new people make the same mistake due to [this](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/datalayer?hl=en#installation) poorly designed gtm/gtag page of google's documentation.

In general, however, when you're debugging page load, you don't want to end your investigation on the lighthouse report. You should continue with Chrome's page load profiling via devtools and analyze the results properly. Lighthouse is often wrong in what it highlights as a problem. A lot of what it highlights doesn't actually affect the  page load times in a measurable way.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand all of this and have been working with GTM since its inception.

This one is a head scratcher though. If I remove just the Google Tag (in GTM) from loading the site loads very fast. As soon as it is added back in it takes 10-13 for TTI. The issue appears to be related to the doubleclick iframe that is called after processing.

Initially there was a GA4 google tag and separate Google Ads google tag loading but I combined it into one and set the GA4 Google Tag destinations to include the Google Ads account as well. Thought that might resolve it but didn't

Comment: TTI is misleading. Try to figure if the page actually becomes interactive before the gtm loads gtag. You'll see that it's completely interactive. Lighthouse probably assumes The page is not interactive until the final mutations to the body are done. And an iframe added to a body may seem to it like a functional mutation. Anyhow, usually the ones who chase the perfect lighthouse score are the SEO people believing Google uses that score for ranking. It doesn't, but they still chase it. Well, low-effort SEOs cost devtime to the rest.

Comment: The main issue is if we remove the gtag from firing it's very fast and as soon as we add it, it's slow again.

Comment: Try these pages

https://www.kegoutlet.com/categories.html vs.
https://www.kegoutlet.com/cart/cart.aspx

They are both loading the same GTM container and all tags.
The first will load then become unresponsive to clicks until the gtag.js script is evaluated.
The cart page loads fine.

Comment: wooow... Thanks for sharing this. This is not supposed to happen. All seems fine there. But yeah, I can see the main thread being blocked seemingly for no reason. I'll ask my colleagues to take a look at it and get back to you. I suspect some conflicts with the front-end. But we'll see.

Comment: can you find which tag in GTM exactly causes the delay? it's not the doubleclick iframe. It's something that uses gtag. Maybe it's a piece of CHTML or a CJS variable that does unsavory things.

Comment: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-23PE1G204X&l=dataLayer&cx=c
Is the offending script. Until you load up a page that doesn't contain all the Cateogories in the side Nav like the cart.aspx page and then it's fine.

Comment: yes, it seems like this regex is the offender: [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,} which is a part of assessing user data. Which is not GA's business to do on it's own. GA keeps trying to do more than needed from them. Check that you don't have the [automatic user data collection](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/13262500?hl=en#Automatic_collection) enabled.

Comment: Here, seems like [Simo's gone through this thing](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/simoahava_edit-ive-updated-this-text-to-emphasize-activity-7140671108315332608-g2wI) too a week ago. Great job Google. Another not needed feature that does more harm than good. And why not enable it by default? Heh.

Comment: Disabled this feature and seems a bit better but still hanging.

Comment: Did you disable it both in GA4 and GTM? I see the regex is no longer there but it still takes its sweet time.

Comment: the new stack trace is not as obvious. Here's the screenshot of it: https://i.imgur.com/Gr8GD8x.jpg from looking at the function calls, I can't say what it does. Maybe at this point it would suffice to start disabling more and more of the GA4/Gtag features until you stumble upon the offender...

Comment: Maybe check things like enhanced measurement events. Disable them.

Comment: Disabled all enhanced measurement events and still about the same. :( Better than it was but still not right.

Comment: I'm still seeing [this](https://i.imgur.com/NcbJKab.jpg) function participating in the 1 second pageload delay stack trace. This indicates to me that you haven't disabled the user-provided data detection stuff. Make sure you're diasabling it in the right GA4 property and the correct GTM container.

Comment: Not sure where I'm disabling this in the GTM container though? I have turned it off in GA4.

Comment: Sorry, I meant gtag. http://tagmanager.google.com/ -> Google tags tab. It should reflect GA's settings. The GA4 property you should make changes to would be the one starting with G-23PE

Comment: Yes, that is where I made the changes both in GA4 and the Google Tag settings and are both set to disable that feature.

The GTM tag doesn't have that option https://snipboard.io/hKoM6k.jpg
Gtag settings - https://snipboard.io/4TOFc8.jpg

Comment: And the email regular expression is back in game: https://i.imgur.com/vcoD4GG.jpg Well, try disabling gtag-reliant pixels and gtm tags one by one. Try making a new ga4 property and using code from it instead with the default settings. I don't think I can get much deeper technically from where we are.

Comment: I did notice that we initially had a separate gtag firing for the Google Ads destination and it suffered the same issue. If I removed that tag everything was fast. I then removed that one and made the existing GA4 gtag also send data to the Google Ads account as a new destination and the issue returned. So something in the Google Ads must be the issue.

Comment: So... Normally we send pixels to GAds explicitly via a TMS. By deploying something like : `gtag('config','AW-123123123')` or `gtag('event', 'conversion',{'send_to':'DC-123123/conversion/something-something'})`We don't allow gtag to do anything on it's own.